# How to send emails using mailgun in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, email, mailgun

I am using the following code to send emails in angularjs using the mailgun API.

```
.controller("MailgunController", function($scope, $http) {

  var mailgunUrl = "YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE";
  var mailgunApiKey = window.btoa("api:key-YOUR_API_KEY_HERE")

  $scope.send = function() {
    $http({
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + mailgunUrl + "/messages",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + mailgunApiKey
      },
      data: "from=" + "test@example.com" + "&to=" + "soeone@gmail.com" + "&subject=" + "MailgunTest" + "&text=" + "EmailBody"
    }).then(function(success) {
      console.log("SUCCESS " + JSON.stringify(success));
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("ERROR " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }

})
```

But I am getting the following error!

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MY-URL/messages. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I had changed the following things in my code

1. YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE *with* with-my-domain
2. key-YOUR_API_KEY_HERE *with* with-my-api-key

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Also, you can add [CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/reviews?hl=en) to Google Chrome.

Comment: @Rizwan does this works for you? I have just opened a similar issue --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931250/send-email-with-mailgun-in-angular